# Unable to remove directory after running unit tests with Flask and pytest

Tags: unit-testing, flask, pytest, contextmanager

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Flask application using pytest. After running my tests, I want to clean up the ./log folder. Currently, I'm using a context manager to create and remove the directory, but I'm running into an issue where the ./log folder is still in use by the application's handles even after the tests have finished.

Here's the code for the context manager:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def create_and_remove_directory(path):
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(path)
```

And here's the fixture I'm using to instantiate the app:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    with create_and_remove_directory("./log/"):
        app = create_dysphagia_predictor_app('dysphagia_predictor.config.TestingConfig',
                                             'config.DevelopmentConfig',
                                             logging.DEBUG)

        with create_and_remove_directory(app.config['MODEL_TESTING']):
            yield app
```

Despite using the context manager to remove the ./log folder, I still can't delete it because it's still in use by the application's handles. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?